# Will all my files be deleted if I choose 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu' when installing in a VMWare virtual machine?

Tags: partitioning

I have downloaded VMWare Workstation Player and Ubuntu .iso file. My PC runs on Windows 10 (this is the only OS of the PC). While installing Ubuntu it asks for the installation type, and I am a little bit confused.

If I choose 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu, will my PC's all my hard drive be formatted, including files stored in the Windows OS, which is not a VM, or VMs see only the storage allocated for themselves?

If I create new partitions via 'Something else' option, will it overwrite my C: and D: disks on Windows OS?

[image]

Comment: Wait, I didn't understand. Are you installing ubuntu inside the VM or on the system.

Comment: If it is inside the VM then there is nothing to be afraid of, but if you are installing Ubuntu on the main system then yes, erase and install will format the entire drive, make it a single partition drive(+1 for swap) and then install ubuntu over it

Comment: Thanks. I install it on VM @akabhirav. So in a VM I can use the 'Erase disk' option. Is it safe? I am using VMWare

Comment: yes, it is safe

Comment: I think you guys misunderstood her question, when creating a new disk via vmware tools a 20 gb disk space is allotted . So when you run erase disk and install ubuntu , it only means that 20 gb allotted out of your C,D drive etc that is asked to be erased. This is done so that new filesystem can be mounted on that partition. Since the OP is running Windows 10 and is allotting 20 GB out 100 GB disk space is C , that does mean that 20GB of the disk space will be used however remaining 80GB of area **will have NO impact whatsoever.**
Only thing you have to care for is : in that 20GB partition if y

Comment: When you create a virtual machine with a virtual disk, you can do 'anything you want' with that virtual disk (running a guest operating system) without any damage to the host operating system and its file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question comes in two sets... So I will answer as such:

- Yes... If you choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" your **whole** hard drive will be formatted. "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" means you are authorizing the setup to erase your hard drive completely.
- It is good to create a partition while you are on Windows OS, and then make use of it through the "Something else" option.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, thanks. The problem is, I created and initialized 20GB HDD partition on Windows, intended for Linux, but when I choose 'Something else' option it does not appear there(is not visible). All other drives are not visible too. What I should do then?

Comment: @EleonoraGrigoryan what do you see when you choose "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation"? Just to know something...

Comment: @EleonoraGrigoryan do you know what kind of hard drive is in the computer?  SSD?  SATA?  NVMe?  it might be relevant for the question, as Ubuntu has historically had some problems with NVMe / M.2 SSDs.

Comment: Regarding 1: this is true for an install to DISK. An install with a VM is inside a FILE. There is no c: d: or other operating system inside a VM besides the one you install.

Comment: I'm yet to understand why this answer is being severely downvoted meanwhile it was helpful to the OP and solved their issue. Does this mean I should delete my answer?

Answer (score 7):

If you are installing Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine, only the drives that are components of the virtual machine can be installed to. You can safely check by selecting the "Something Else" option with the installer. Here's an example in Virtualbox:

[image]

As you can see from the size and labeling the disk it's considering is most certainly too small to be an actual drive in my machine. It's a good idea to check the sizes of drives and partitions on your system and be familiar with them to avoid any mistakes. The size will be equivalent to the size you chose when you created the disk file (virtual disk) that the Virtual Machine actually uses.

Another indication that you are installing to a disk file and not a physical drive is that the installer is not providing the option to install alongside your host OS (Windows) as the VM doesn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

Select **‘Erase disk and install Ubuntu’**. Don’t worry. It won’t delete anything on your Windows operating system. You are using the virtual disk space of 15-20GB that we created in previous steps. It won’t impact the real operating system.

**I installed Ubuntu about an hour ago, selected the above option, and everything's working fine like before.**

Comment: @Rinzwind As I understand it, the installation is being performed *in a virtual machine*, and the Windows system is the host. So *on that specific case*, using "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" does not risk loss of data in "files stored in the Windows OS, which is not a VM" (as the question puts it). It occurs to me that the most important text in this answer--"You are using the virtual disk space..."--should probably be what is bolded, rather than the other parts, but this answer does seem to be correct, with respect to the specific situation described in the question here.