# Ubuntu installer with two disks: whihc one will be selected by "erase disk and install"

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have two disks on my computer, with:

- `sda`: backup disk (has 12.04)
- `sdb`: disk for system (has now 18.04)

Making a fresh install, I want to use the option *erase disk and install Ubuntu* (so that I can use encryption, otherwise I would just use option *something else*), on `sdb`, not `sda`. The installer correctly recognized there are two systems,  but says: *will delete all ... in all operating systems*

How can I make sure it installs on `sdb`? Or will it really erase both disks?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Which release are you trying to install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After clicking Continue the next screen will ask you to confirm and shows which disks would be changed:

[image: Screenshot of Prompt]

Comment: great, thanks! the Button *Install Now* is confusing in that regard, I did not dare to try it...

Comment: I just installed Xubuntu 20 with LVM and encryption enabled and it actually allowed me to select which disk I wanted to wipe. I think that's new, I haven't seen this in Ubuntu installers before. It still said that it'll wipe all data in all operating systems though, so it's a little clunky for something so crucial.

Comment: Very helpful given the fact that I have four drives, two of which are data only, one of which has 18.04, and one of which has 20.04 which didn't get ZFS like I wanted because it wasn't an option when I tried "Something else".

Comment: What I don't see in your screenshot though is exactly how you select *which* drive to erase and install to.

Comment: well great, it gives me four identical looking choices *because they are identical drive models*

Comment: it's also unclear if it's going to use the existing drive with an EFI partition (different drive) or if it's going to needlessly create *another* extra partition  on the drive I'm telling it to erase.

Comment: Looks different from screenshots on Ubuntu 20.10, but can confirm you get to choose disk there as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very similar* question to [Will all my files be deleted if I choose 'Erase disk and Install Ubuntu' when installing in a VMWare virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094191/will-all-my-files-be-deleted-if-i-choose-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-when-in) although that one seems to be from the Ubuntu 18 era.

I just went through the process again on Ubuntu 20.04 with two drives: one with an old Ubuntu installation I wanted to replace and a second with an OEM Windows 10 installation. I selected the "Erase Everything and Install Ubuntu" rather than the "Erase Ubuntu 18.05.4 and Install Ubuntu" or the "Something else" options. Even though the button "Install Now" feels very final, clicking on it in this version actually takes you to a subsequent screen where you are asked to select *which* drive on which to "Erase Everything and Install Ubuntu".

Comment: if you have windows also installed it will not respect your disk selection and replace the windows bootloader with grub.